# Appending text between 2 specific characters of HTML

Tags: html, vb.net, string, append

I am trying to filter out specific text from a set of HTML string and I am having trouble writing code to do so in Visual Basic. The problem I am trying to solve is;

< A NAME=SECT1>< B>JOHN< /B>< /A>

< A NAME=1.1.10>Have you had a good night?< /A>< br>

From this I want only to append the following;

JOHN

Have you had a good night?

**Note: I had to enter a few extra spaces to keep this from converting out of HTML.

I have tried to write a few different sub routines to append the text between the 2nd ">" and 3rd "<" if the 9th character is a "S" and to append the text between the 1st ">" and 2nd "<" if the 9th character is not a "S".

This is the main idea that I have been trying, but I haven't been able to find the right code to put inside the Then.

```
 For Each line As String In AnalyzedText
        Dim chars() = line.ToCharArray
        If chars.Length >= 9 AndAlso chars(8) = "S"c Then
            'Not sure what would go here
        ElseIf chars.Length >= 9 AndAlso chars(8) <> "S"c Then
            'Not sure what would go here
        End If
    Next
```

I apologize that I have not been able to make more progress, but I honestly have no idea where to go from here and have tried everything I can think of. Any help or ideas you have will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work with your attempt and made a running version out of it. However as soon as something changes the code will break.

What happens if < A NAME=1.1.10> is < A NAME=1.1.9> instead? The lengths will not be proper. You could solve that with using substring not with hard coded lengths but with the '>' signs. Use IndexOf and LastIndexOf in combination with substring several multiple times.

What happens if the tags are not one of the two? You could throw an exception

I would suggest using regular expression for this kind of problem. Have a look at a regex. You can test it with a online regex runner. It is a much cleaner solution than the one i proposed

regex vb tutorial:
http://www.vb-paradise.de/index.php/Thread/34042-RegEx-Tutorial-Blutige-Anf%C3%A4nger-und-Fortgeschrittene/

runner:
http://www.myregextester.com/

here the code for your example. Note that it will break under the conditions I described. If you have further progress with your problem I can help you again. I hope this gets you to the right direction.

```
    Dim inputList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim outputList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

    Dim sectAsStringLengthBefore As Integer = "< A NAME=SECT1>< B>".Length
    Dim sectAsStringLengthAfter As Integer = "< /B>< /A>".Length
    Dim sectAsStringMinimumLength As Integer = sectAsStringLengthBefore + sectAsStringLengthAfter

    Dim sectAsNumericLengthBefore As Integer = "< A NAME=1.1.10>".Length
    Dim sectAsNumericLengthAfter As Integer = "< /A>< br>".Length
    Dim sectAsNumericMinimumLength As Integer = sectAsNumericLengthBefore + sectAsNumericLengthAfter

    inputList.Add("< A NAME=SECT1>< B>JOHN< /B>< /A>")
    inputList.Add("< A NAME=1.1.10>Have you had a good night?< /A>< br>")

    For Each line As String In inputList
        If line.Length >= sectAsStringMinimumLength AndAlso line(9) = "S"c Then
            outputList.Add(line.Substring(sectAsStringLengthBefore, line.Length - sectAsStringMinimumLength))
        ElseIf line.Length >= sectAsNumericMinimumLength AndAlso line(9) <> "S"c Then
            outputList.Add(line.Substring(sectAsNumericLengthBefore, line.Length - sectAsNumericMinimumLength))
        End If
    Next
```